# Customise Bootstrap open nav anchor background colour

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using the [Bootstrap Customizer](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) to generate a config file I can distribute to clients, from which they can base their sites (using my custom styles).

It's working okay except for one thing.  To provide additional levels of navigation (something Bootstrap doesn't do out of the box) I'm using [Smartmenus](http://www.smartmenus.org/) which applies a class of 'open' to the nav `li` element which is currently open (i.e when the list item is hovered).

In the un-minified Bootstrap css which is output by the customizer are the following rules:

```
.nav .open > a,
.nav .open > a:hover,
.nav .open > a:focus {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  border-color: #337ab7;
}
```

So all I want to do is change `#eeeeee` to something else but I can't see where in the configuration tool I can set this value.  It must be set via a 'lighten' or 'darken' Less method as there's nothing in there with a straight value of `#eeeeee`, but I can't spot where it's coming from.

I'm aware that I could easily add an override with some custom CSS to do this, but I would really like to do it in the configuration tool so that I can pass the config file over to clients without having to add custom bits of CSS and caveats for them.

Can anyone see where in the configuration tool I can affect this value?

Many thanks.

Comment: look for `@nav-link-hover-bg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you download the Bootstrap source code you will find that the above css code had been defined in the `less/navs.less`

// Open dropdowns
  .open > a {
    &,
    &:hover,
    &:focus {
      background-color: @nav-link-hover-bg;
      border-color: @link-color;
    }
  }

`less/variables.less` defines `@nav-link-hover-bg` as follows:

```
@nav-link-hover-bg:                         @gray-lighter;
```

and:

```
//## Gray and brand colors for use across Bootstrap.

@gray-base:              #000;
@gray-darker:            lighten(@gray-base, 13.5%); // #222
@gray-dark:              lighten(@gray-base, 20%);   // #333
@gray:                   lighten(@gray-base, 33.5%); // #555
@gray-light:             lighten(@gray-base, 46.7%); // #777
@gray-lighter:           lighten(@gray-base, 93.5%); // #eee
```

Comment: Wonderful, thanks :)  I was focussed on the 'Nav' section of the configuration tool and completely missed the 'Navs' section (which sets some common styles amongst all navigation).